# How to create a combo box in swish max?

Tags: flash, combobox, swish

Please help me create a combo box in swish max.
I searched for ready-made components, but it's not there in swish.

How can I do this?

Comment: did you have a look to Flash CS5 IDE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for it.
follow these steps =>

1 -> Create a dynamic text box
2 -> draw an down arrow in front of it
3 -> for a click on arrow autoshape create an movieclip below the dynamic text box
4 -> This movieclip must contain the collection of buttons and each button must contain a value
5 -> for respective clicks on buttons inside a movie clip update the dynamic select textbox

```
 on (press) {
    select = "MBA";
    _root.dept1.text = "MBA";
}


on (release) { 
_root.gotoAndStop("home"); 
}
```